# Как лучше организовать маршрутизацию на мультиязычном сайте?

Tags: laravel, seo, оптимизация-сайтов

На [форуме фреймворка Laravel](https://laravel.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?id=2873) мне было сказано, что в целях хорошей поисковой оптимизации на мультиязычных сайтах разные языки должны быть разнесены по разным URI. Но как именно лучше разделить маршруты для одних и тех же страниц на разных языках?

Популярны следующие два варианта:

- Доменное имя третьего уровния: `ru.example.com/somepage`, `en.example.com/somepage`. Такой подход использовался на момент написания этого вопроса, например, на [сайте Московского Авиационного института](https://www.mai.ru/) (для английской версии сайта).
- Часть URN: `example.com/ru/`, `example.com/en/` и т. д. Такой подход использовался на момент написания этого вопроса, например, на [сайте Высшей Школы Экономики](https://www.hse.ru/) (для английской и китайской версии сайта).

Есть ли какие-нибудь причины, по которым один подход лучше другого?

Comment: Вариант en.example.com даёт больше возни с https-сертификатами

Answer (score 1):

[Курим доки Гугла](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=ru)

[Курим доки Яндекса](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/yandex-indexing/locale-pages.html)

Никакого преимущества ни первый, ни второй вариант не дает. Также посмотрите вариант использования ru-ru/ru-en , если необходимо разделить контент по геолокации.